# Bootstrap not loading in some page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I am new to bootstrap and UI stuff. 
Was trying implementation of grid by following this doc
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Came across this strange UI issue in my rails 5 app.
We use these gems 'bootstrap-sass'(3.3.7) and 'bootstrap_form' (2.7.0)

We have included boostrap admin.html.erb.

```
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```

However, in some admin pages bootstrap seems to be loading.
[image]

Whereas in some other admin pages, like the one below, bootstrap is just not loading.
[image]
Not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin part of my project is using bootstrapv2.3.2
Though my project includes 'bootstrap-sass'(3.3.7) in the Gemfile, it is rendered only in non-admin parts of my project.
The admin part renders under a different layout which uses bootstrapv2.3.2

bootstrap2.3.2 had custom styling for class name `span`, however it did not support `col-md-*`.

`col-md-*` was introduced in bootstrap 3 and used in higher versions as well.

That is why in pages where I have used `span`, bootstrap styling got applied.
When I tried using `col-md` bootstrap styling did not get applied.

Answer (score 2):

First, Bootstrap 2.3.2 is [no longer supported](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) so I would recommend upgrading to a later version.

Second, you should really use one of the Bootstrap Gems, which comes with step-by-step instructions specific to Rails

For Bootstrap 2 and 3: [Bootstrap Sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

For Bootstrap 4: [Bootstrap Ruby Gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem)

Because you are new to Bootstrap, I would also recommend using Bootstrap 4 (unless you have a reason not to do so).